# Display image sequence as overlapping stack

Tags: image, matlab

For a presentation I would like a sequence of images (essentially frames of a film) displayed with each frame displayed behind and offset relative to the previous.

Only the first frame is totally visible, but you will see part of the remaining frames.

Can this be done in matlab or in some (freeware) program ?

[image: example]

Comment: Matlab can do  **E V E R Y T H I N G**!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sequence of images are stored in a cell array `seq`, and all images are of the same size.
Is this what you had on your mind?

```
sz=size(seq{1}); %// assuming all frames are of the same size
m = 20; %// size of "margin" to show from each frame
n = numel( seq ); %// number of frames in sequence
fh = figure('Position', [100 100 sz(2)+(n-1)*m sz(1)] ); 
ah=axes('Units','pixels','Position', [ 0 0 sz(2)+(n-1)*m sz(1)] ); 
hold on;
%// show frames from last to first
for fi=n:-1:1
    imshow( seq{fi}, 'Parent', ah, 'XData', (fi-1)*m + (1:sz(2)));
end
```

I am using the `XData` property of `imshow` to move the frames with respect to each other.
You might also want to explor `YData` to create a vertical shift as well...

Comment: This very close to what I wanted, thank you very much